Ncurses - How to handle terminal resizes for an image that is being updated in an infinite loop
I have a program utilizing ncurses to draw a window with a clock timer. It is constantly being refreshed in an infinite loop. It works as intended, however when I resize the terminal window, the entire image gets messed up and all out of sorts.
I've read some items on SIGWINCH for ncurses as well as a few others but they are all relying on a wgetch(win) or getch(). These calls block the loop waiting for user input. This seems like a pretty standard use-case, so trying to understand what is the procedure for detecting the window resizing without blocking the loop.
Note I am on Windows 11 and to compile I run gcc -o test.exe test.c -lncurses -DNCURSES_STATIC
#include <windows.h>
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

// default window sizes
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 16
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 45
#define WINDOW_START_Y 5
#define WINDOW_START_X 5

// prototypes
WINDOW *init_window(void);

int main(void)
{
        // global screen init
        initscr();
        WINDOW *win;
        win = init_window();
        refresh();

        // hide cursor
        curs_set(0);

        // draw basic box in the window
        box(win, 0, 0);

        // initialize the timer
        time_t now;
        while (1) {
                
                // update current UTC time
                now = time(0);
                struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&now);

                // modify terminal window
                mvwprintw(win, 1, 1, "           _________           ");
                mvwprintw(win, 2, 1, "          / ======= \\         ");
                mvwprintw(win, 3, 1, "         / __________\\        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 4, 1, "        | ___________ |        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 5, 1, "        | | -       | |        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 6, 1, "        | |         | |              ");
                mvwprintw(win, 7, 1, "        | |_________| |________________  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 8, 1, "        \\=____________/      REM       ) ");
                mvwprintw(win, 9, 1, "        / \"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\" \\               /  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 1, "       / ::::::::::::: \\          =D-'   ");
                mvwprintw(win, 11, 1, "      (_________________)                  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 12, 1, "      current time: %02d:%02d:%02d", tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);
                wrefresh(win);
        }

        // clean up
        endwin();
        return 0;
}

WINDOW* init_window(void)
{
        // create new window
        WINDOW *win = newwin(WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_START_Y, WINDOW_START_X);
        if (!win) {
                printf("ERROR: could not create window\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        return win;
}


I'm not sure about Windows-specific details, but you can either wait for event on stdin file descriptor with timeout, or set stdin to non-blocking mode and poll it periodically. Or wait on two descriptors: periodic timer and stdin. Call getch() only if it would not block.

This should be a duplicate, but the essential point combining SIGWINCH and polled input doesn't appear.
So... modify the program to

use wgetch with no time delay, to allow it to read KEY_RESIZE
the window should be resized to allow for the margins, etc
drawing the window on each call to time is wasteful (check and skip)

Here's a modified program which illustrates those points:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

// default window sizes
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT LINES - 2
#define WINDOW_WIDTH COLS - 2
#define WINDOW_START_Y 1
#define WINDOW_START_X 1

// prototypes
WINDOW *init_window(void);

int main(void)
{
        initscr();
        cbreak();
        WINDOW *win = init_window();
        nodelay(win, TRUE);

        // hide cursor
        curs_set(0);

        // draw basic box in the window
        box(win, 0, 0);

        // initialize the timer
        time_t start = time(0);
        while (1) {
                if (wgetch(win) == KEY_RESIZE) {        // process SIGWINCH
                        wresize(win, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH);
                        clear();
                        wclear(win);
                        box(win, 0, 0);
                        wnoutrefresh(win);
                        start--;        // force a redraw
                }
                
                // update current UTC time
                time_t now = time(0);

                if (now == start)
                        continue;
                start = now;

                struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&now);

                // modify terminal window
                mvwprintw(win, 1, 1, "           _________           ");
                mvwprintw(win, 2, 1, "          / ======= \\         ");
                mvwprintw(win, 3, 1, "         / __________\\        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 4, 1, "        | ___________ |        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 5, 1, "        | | -       | |        ");
                mvwprintw(win, 6, 1, "        | |         | |              ");
                mvwprintw(win, 7, 1, "        | |_________| |________________  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 8, 1, "        \\=____________/      REM       ) ");
                mvwprintw(win, 9, 1, "        / \"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\" \\               /  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 10, 1, "       / ::::::::::::: \\          =D-'   ");
                mvwprintw(win, 11, 1, "      (_________________)                  ");
                mvwprintw(win, 12, 1, "      current time: %02d:%02d:%02d", tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);
                wnoutrefresh(win);
                doupdate();
        }

        // clean up
        endwin();
        return 0;
}

WINDOW* init_window(void)
{
        // create new window
        WINDOW *win = newwin(WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_START_Y, WINDOW_START_X);
        if (!win) {
                printf("ERROR: could not create window\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        return win;
}

Now... the answer as posted is ambiguous regarding whether this is (for example) using Cygwin, MinGW or MSYS2.  The MinGW configuration doesn't provide a workable KEY_RESIZE; if you are using that, this question should be marked as a duplicate.  Otherwise, if the underlying libraries are more-or-less POSIX, the program will work for you.

Thanks for your answer. I noticed that using MSYS terminal I still get some funky resizing behavior. I have tried with mingw64 terminal and the behavior seems similar. I have not yet tried on Cygwin to confirm. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Cygwin gives same behavior as MSYS and MINGW64 on Windows 11.

Let's put aside resizes for a second. Even without resizes, your program is not good.
It runs in an infinite loop without any delay, asking ncurses to update the display probably many-many thousands of times per second, spinning one of the CPUs to its max, taking away resources from other apps, draining the battery etc.
You should include a sleep() or so. Don't sleep for 1 second because then the clock can be delayed by up to 1 second (on average 0.5 seconds), and can eventually result in skips of a displayed second (if that 1 second happens to become 1.0001 seconds jumping over two integers). Instead, query the current time including subseconds (with gettimeofday() or clock_gettime()) and sleep for the remaining part of the current second. If you want to update the screen continuously (e.g. show milliseconds) then sleep according to the human eye's perception or the assumed display update rate, e.g. around 1/60s.
Now, you want this sleep to be interrupted on a SIGWINCH. The good news is: by default it will be interrupted, so probably no further action is required here. I'm not familiar with the ncurses part though, maybe you need to tell it somehow that the window size changed. But how do you know if the window was resized? Maybe you don't care; you just update ncurses each time with the window size (if that step is needed; again, I'm not that familiar with ncurses off the top of my head); if it's done once per second or per window resize then it's absolutely okay.
The really proper solution if you want your app to scale, want to add more features (such as input handling) in the future, or want to actually know if a window resize occurred; and if you want to do all this "manually":
Block SIGWINCH delivery (sigprocmask()). Install a SIGWINCH handler that flips a global boolean (sigaction()). Replace the sleep() call with a pselect() (or ppoll()) that atomically enables SIGWINCH delivery only for the duration of this pselect() call. Set up this pselect() for the timeout you want, and also watch for the file descriptors if you wish to (i.e. file descriptor 0 if you want to read data whenever it's available on standard input). After this pselect() call check if the global boolean of SIGWINCH is set; if it is then take proper actions (whatever you need to do to handle the resize; maybe tell it to ncurses if needed) and clear that flag.
There exist libraries out there that can conveniently do it for you, e.g. if you're using GLib then you can set up everything you wish to handle, and then enter a "main loop" which does this work for you. You might want to check ncurses's documentation to see if it has such a "main loop" feature too, I'm not sure if it has. Or of course you can stick to the "manual" approach outlined in the previous paragraph, it's not that hard once you grasp the basic concepts behind, and it's a standard pattern so I'm sure you'll find many examples showing it.

Thanks for the critiques. This program is taking <0.5% of my current CPU when it is running, but I will take this note to heart. Also as mentioned in my question this is on Windows and I believe a lot of your advice is for Linux.

You're right, I was thinking about Linux, I completely missed that you're on Windows.
